# Who named the fugacity, who coined the variable name and did it already relate to complex analysis?

Tags: theoretical-physics, number-theory, statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, complex-analysis

In Riemanns monumental paper, he expresses a prime counting function as an inverse Mellin transform of the log of the function he analytically continued into the complex plane

$$\Pi(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int \log \zeta(s)\ x^s \frac{\mathrm{d}s}{s}$$

and the zeros of $\zeta$ are consequently of interest (Riemann hypothesis).

Associated quantities relate closely to concepts in statistical physics. [Planck's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) of for the spectral radiance ($B_\nu(\nu, T) = 2 h c^{-2}\frac{\nu^3}{e^{h\nu/k_\mathrm{B}T} - 1}$) Mellin transforms to the Riemann zeta function ($\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x ^ {s-1}}{e ^ x - 1} \mathrm{d}x$) and physicists have their own [polylog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) (mind the $z$) in the [Fermi–Dirac integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_integral).

Now the [grand partition function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_%28statistical_mechanics%29#Grand_canonical_partition_function) $\mathcal{Z}$ relates microscopic statistical physics to thermodynamics via

$$-k_B T \ln \mathcal{Z} = \langle E \rangle - TS - \mu \langle N\rangle$$

and is often expressed as a power series in the fugacity $$z=\exp\left(\frac{\mu}{T}\right)$$ as
$\mathcal{Z}(z) = \sum_{N_i} z^{N_i} Z(N_i).$

The zeros of $\mathcal{Z}$ in $z$ make the log $\ln \mathcal{Z}$ explode and this phenomenon is associated with phase transitions 
and people study and cook up result like the [Lee-Yang-theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee%E2%80%93Yang_theorem). 
The fugacity as a parameter in $\mathbb C$, which controls the zeros, is actually on the cover of one of my favorite books. But I'd think the fugacity was defined without that context in mind.

What I wanted to know is when did "$z$" become a standard name for a //complex// variable and, more importantly, is it coincidence that the names fit?? Who names it and where there other names for the fugaciy?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is a coincidence.

The concept of **fugacity** (from the Latin for "fleetness, tendency to flee") was originally introduced by [Gilbert Lewis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_N._Lewis) in his 1901 paper "[The Law of Physico-Chemical Change](https://archive.org/details/jstor-20021635)" for the pressure of an ideal gas which has the same chemical potential as a real gas. Lewis notated this with **ψ**, though these days the letter **f** is used.

The concept of **complex fugacity** was introduced by Lee and Lang in their 1952 paper "[Statistical Theory of Equations of State and Phase Transitions](http://ergodic.ugr.es/statphys/bibliografia/yang1.pdf)". The complex fugacity plane was originally notated **y**, though as you note these days the letter **z** is used. I'm not sure precisely how old the use of z for a generic complex variable is but it dates to at least the 1890s (e.g. see [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?ei=LL_1VMiLHoa0sATxhYKwDA&id=xVmqAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22complex%20variable%20z%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22complex%20variable%20z%22)).

The concept of **partition function** was introduced by Planck in 1921. Its use of the letter **Z** comes from its original German name,  Zustandssumme ("sum over states"). The English name is due to Darwin and Fowler (1922).